# Xcode Application Loader Errors - How to bypass ipad multitasking support orientation requirements?

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

[image: Image Tag]

So I get these errors just when I was uploading the app in appstore. Please click Image Tag if the image does not load.

I would like to know if we can bypass the ipad multitasking support orientation requirements?

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: Is their a way to bypass the ipad multitasking support orientation requirements? I really just need to launch the app in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but you can opt it out by below step:

just add `UIRequiresFullScreen` key in `.plist` file of project and set the Boolean value `YES`.

**Or**

open project `.plist` file using text editor and below lines:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: Happy to help! @ChrisMikkelsen